# any simple way to integrate products involving sign functions?

Tags: integration

I have many indefinite integrals to perform of the type

$$I = \int du f'(u)\text{sign}(u-u_0).$$

My current approach is to separate into cases:

$$ I = \int du \begin{cases} f'(u) & u-u_0>0 \\ -f'(u) & u-u_0<0 \end{cases} = \begin{cases} f(u) & u-u_0>0 \\ -f(u) & u-u_0<0 \end{cases}  = f(u)\text{sign}(u-u_0).$$

Do these always evaluate this way, with the $\text{sign}(x)$ function passing through the integral sign, or are there any caveats? Does anything change if the integrals are definite?

bonus: Does this generalize to multiple sign functions as in $I = \int du f'(u)\prod_i \text{sign}(u-u_i) = f(u)\prod_i\text{sign}(u-u_i)$?

Comment: Integrate over the region $u>u_0$.  Then integrate over the region $u<u_0$.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but I just rephrased the question.

Comment: The caveat is that the function $f(u)sign(u-u_0)$ may not be differentiable at $u=u_0$ and so I would not think of that function as being an "antiderivative."  You also cannot use it for definite integrals  $\int_a^b$ if $u_0 \in (a,b)$.  You would need to say $\int_a^b = \int_a^{u_0} + \int_{u_0}^b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does generalize. Let $g(u) = f'(u) \prod_{i = 1}^n \operatorname{sgn} (u - u_i)$. Suppose $u_i$ are ordered, then $g$ equals $f'$ times a constant on $(u_i, u_{i + 1})$. Then $f$ times the same constant is an antiderivative for $g$ on $(u_i, u_{i + 1})$.

The jumps in the antiderivative between the intervals will be equal to $2 (-1)^{n - i} f(u_i)$, therefore an antiderivative which has only removable discontinuities at $u_i$ is
$$G(u) = f(u) \prod_{i = 1}^n \operatorname{sgn}(u - u_i) -
 2 \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{n - i} f(u_i) H(u - u_i),$$
where $H$ is the unit step function. When $G$ is defined by continuity at $u_i$, the integral of $g$ over any $[a, b]$ is $G(b) - G(a)$.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay accepting the answer. This was very helpful